# Group HITs into batches in amazon mechanical turk with boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, mechanicalturk

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.toforge.com/2011/04/boto-mturk-tutorial-create-hits/) to create HITs on amazon Mturk.  I notice, however, that all my HITs are listed as individual tasks---I have to click on "manage HITs individually" in the [upper right, here](http://content.screencast.com/users/harryf/folders/Jing/media/f7348e71-9623-4ec3-8a41-d83a1cf14e1f/00000552.png), rather than see anything under the "batches in progress" link.

I can't seem to find how to group boto-created HITs, even after checking the docs:
http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/mturk.html

But found this on Amazon suggesting this is still an open problem:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=24993

Any thoughts or updates or does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't create batches through the API. Lots of discussion of this on the AWS forums and there is no way to do it.

Comment: Is there any way to append some kind of group-like label to them so you can at least organize them for common batch-like operations?  Like "expire early all the individual ones that were launched in a group?"

Comment: A batch is essentially a subset of a HITType, so you could expire everything of a given HITTypeId. Alternatively, you could use the "requester annotation" field to apply a label to a group of HITs and then use that. Batches created on the website actually insert a batch-specific annotation, so you could mimic that to some extent.

Comment: Thanks, that's super helpful.  Pushing my luck: any chance you have some minimal code appending annotations, and demonstrating select-by-annotation?  =)

Comment: I don't use boto, so anything I have probably won't be helpful. Workflow would involve doing a SearchHITs operation, then subsetting the results of that by annotation, and then you'd have HITIds to perform whatever additional operation (e.g., expire).